# how a javascript scope can be duplicated? by using for loop?

Tags: javascript, comet

I just had this javascript comet call working properly, but found out i need 30 pieces to do the same function but with different value output. check out my code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var Comet = Class.create();
   Comet.prototype = { 
    timestamp: 0,
    url: 'backend.php',  
    noerror: true,
    pointname: 'GrossElectricityGeneration',
   initialize: function() { }, 
  connect: function()
  {
  this.ajax = new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
  method: 'get',
  parameters: { 'timestamp' : this.timestamp, 'pointname': this.pointname},
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    // handle the server response
    var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
    this.comett.timestamp = response['timestamp'];
    this.comett.handleResponse(response);
    this.comett.noerror = true;
    },
    onComplete: function(transport) {
    // send a new ajax request when this request is finished
    if (!this.comett.noerror)
      // if a connection problem occurs, try to reconnect each 5 seconds
      setTimeout(function(){ comett.connect() }, 5000); 
    else
      this.comett.connect();
    this.comett.noerror = false;
     }
  });
  this.ajax.comett = this;
 },

 disconnect: function()
{
 },

 handleResponse: function(response)
 {

  $('page1b').innerHTML = '<div>' + response['msg'] +'</div>'; 
 $('page1c').innerHTML = '<div>' + '67'+'</div>';    
  }, 
 }

  var comett = new Comet();
 comett.connect();
 </script>
```

to do this, a silly way is to copy 30 pieces of    ... and rename
comett to 30 different name 
30 different #('page1a')#('page1b')
and point name

is there any other way that i can use for loop to duplicate 30 copies with differnet variables ?

thanks....

Comment: You lost me at the "to do this" part.